# Gaussian Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) of large numbers in Python

Tags: python, statistics, matplotlib, scipy

I have 1000 large numbers, randomly distributed in range 37231 to 56661.

I am trying to use the `stats.gaussian_kde` but something does not work.
(maybe because of my poor knowledge of statistics?).

Here is the code:

```
from scipy import stats.gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 'data' is a 1D array that contains the initial numbers 37231 to 56661
xmin = min(data)
xmax = max(data)   

# get evenly distributed numbers for X axis.
x = linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)   # get 1000 points on x axis
nPoints = len(x)

# get actual kernel density.
density = gaussian_kde(data)
y = density(x)

# print the output data
for i in range(nPoints):
    print "%s   %s" % (x[i], y[i])

plt.plot(x, density(x))
plt.show()
```

In the printout, I get x values in the column 1, and zeros in the column 2.
The plot shows a flat line.

I simply can not find the solution.
I tried a very wide range of X-es, the same result.

What is the problem? What am I doing wrong?
Could the large numbers be the cause?

Comment: Note formatting mistake near the top; you can select all the code and hit `{}` button to add the necessary four spaces before every line.

Comment: @sarnold,
I am sorry, which mistake do you mean?

I actually used that {} button and at least on my Mac the formatting looks fine.

(I am a newbie here and I apologize in advance for the mistake though)

Comment: @Proteos: look at the first line, beginning "from scipy import..".  It's not marked up as code.

Comment: Ha! That'll teach me to give advice without looking at the source code; you have to leave a blank line before source code. It's a bit silly, but you're right, the code was all there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what's happening is that your data array is made up of integers, which leads to problems:

```
>>> import numpy, scipy.stats
>>> 
>>> data = numpy.random.randint(37231, 56661,size=10)
>>> xmin, xmax = min(data), max(data)
>>> x = numpy.linspace(xmin, xmax, 10)
>>> 
>>> density = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(data)
>>> density.dataset
array([[52605, 45451, 46029, 40379, 48885, 41262, 39248, 38247, 55987,
        44019]])
>>> density(x)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

but if we use floats:

```
>>> density = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(data*1.0)
>>> density.dataset
array([[ 52605.,  45451.,  46029.,  40379.,  48885.,  41262.,  39248.,
         38247.,  55987.,  44019.]])
>>> density(x)
array([  4.42201513e-05,   5.51130237e-05,   5.94470211e-05,
         5.78485526e-05,   5.21379448e-05,   4.43176188e-05,
         3.66725694e-05,   3.06297511e-05,   2.56191024e-05,
         2.01305127e-05])
```

Comment: Oh, what a naive mistake!
I thought I was missing something simple but that simple? :)

On the other hand, the gaussian_kde() function should have taken care of converting to float; at least give the warning that it needs floats.
Dont' you agree?

Well, The case is solved!
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Proteos: I agree, this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Nice catch. I could see the argument go either way: the results are being returned with as many digits after the decimal as your input data, and `1e-05` is near enough to `0` for many uses, especially when the inputs are so far from `0`. This is definitely surprising though.

Comment: This has been fixed in scipy and will convert to floats in the next release (scipy 0.10)

Answer (score 3):

I have made a function to do this. You can vary the bandwidth as a parameter of the function. That is, smaller number = more pointy, larger number = smoother. The default is 0.3.

It works in `IPython notebook --pylab=inline`

The number of bins is optimized and coded so will vary on the number of variables in your data.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def hist_with_kde(data, bandwidth = 0.3):
    #set number of bins using Freedman and Diaconis
    q1 = np.percentile(data,25)
    q3 = np.percentile(data,75)


    n = len(data)**(.1/.3)
    rng = max(data) - min(data)
    iqr = 2*(q3-q1)
    bins = int((n*rng)/iqr)

    x = np.linspace(min(data),max(data),200)

    kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data)
    kde.covariance_factor = lambda : bandwidth
    kde._compute_covariance()

    plt.plot(x,kde(x),'r') # distribution function
    plt.hist(data,bins=bins,normed=True) # histogram

data = np.random.randn(500)
hist_with_kde(data,0.25)
```